# Is it possible to create a WorkFlow (in Workflow-foundation -4) dynamically?

Tags: .net, cloud, workflow-foundation-4

Is it possible to create workflows dynamically? I need to generate a WF dynamically based on a set of business logic and service execution sequence I get as input to the system. Is it possible for me to generate the workflow.xaml dynamically without using the wf designer and execute in the cloud ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - you can create xaml file using simple file I/O routines or XML manipulation libraries but the best bet would be using [XamlXmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xaml.xamlxmlwriter.aspx) class.

Once workflow xaml is ready, you can execute it using (as sighted in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc507645.aspx))

```
WorkflowInstance instance = runtime.CreateWorkflow(
      XmlTextReader.Create("..\\..\\WorkflowInXML.xml"));
instance.Start();
```

You can also load activities from xaml in WF4 - check this [article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2010/03/07/loading-xaml-workflows-in-wf4.aspx) for the same.

Comment: The code example and the MSDN article is about WF3 and has no relation to workflow 4. The ActivityXamlServices is the way to go in WF4.

Comment: @Maurice - yes, the article is dated but the method (CreateWorkflow) still exists and relevant - thats why I have quoted it. It must be noted that ActivityXamlServices allows to load only activity tree and not complete workflow.